# MAXIFS excel formula returning 0

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table of transactions and transaction amounts in excel. I am using this forumula to determine the max before a certain date.

=MAXIFS(Transactions[Amount],Transactions[Rec Date],Transactions[Rec Date]&"<="&A2)

A2 in this case equals the date 11/1/16. The forumula returns the value 0.

Any reason this formula is not doing what I want? I have verified the data contains transactions above zero for dates prior to 11/1/16.

Answer (score 0):

It should be =MAXIFS(Transactions[Amount],Transactions[Rec Date],"<="&A2)